# Why loop overwriting my file instead of writing after text?

Tags: python

```
i = 1 # keep track of file number
directory = '/some/directory/'


for i in range(1, 5170): #number of files in directory
    filename = directory + 'D' + str(i) + '.txt'
    input = open(filename)
    output = open('output.txt', 'w')
    input.readline() #ignore first line
    for g in range(0, 7): #write next seven lines to output.txt
        output.write(input.readline())

    output.write('\n') #add newline to avoid mess
    output.close()
    input.close()
    i = i + 1
```

I have this code, and i am trying to get one file and rewrite it to output.txt, but when i want to attach next file, my code overwrite older file that has been attached. In result when code is complete i have something like this:

```
dataA[5169]=26
dataB[5169]=0
dataC[5169]=y
dataD[5169]='something'
dataE[5169]=x
data_date[5169]=2012.06.02
```

Instead of datas ranging from files 0 to 5169. Any tips how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you open in write mode.  To append to file you want to use append.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706499/how-do-you-append-to-file-in-python).

Answer (score 8):

You probably want to open `output.txt` *before* your for loop (and `close` it after).  As it is written, you overwrite the file `output.txt` everytime you open it.  (an alternative would be to open for appending:  `output = open('output.txt','a')`, but that's definitely not the best way to do it here ...

Of course, these days it's better to use a context manager (`with` statement):

```
i = 1 # keep track of file number <-- This line is useless in the code you posted
directory = '/some/directory/'  #<-- os.path.join is better for this stuff.
with open('output.txt','w') as output:

    for i in range(1, 5170): #number of files in directory
        filename = directory + 'D' + str(i) + '.txt'
        with open(filename) as input:

            input.readline() #ignore first line
            for g in range(0, 7): #write next seven lines to output.txt
                output.write(input.readline())

            output.write('\n') #add newline to avoid mess
        i = i + 1   #<---also useless line in the code you posted
```

Comment: @sr2222 -- That's a variant of the same thing I just said :)

Comment: Fair enough.  Though with `with`, your housekeeping is done for you (including exception states, which aren't handled at all here).

Comment: i is not useless, i use it for something else

Comment: @sr2222 -- You're right of course.  (I was in the middle of adding that when you suggested it).  I just want to make it clear that it was a *logic* error, not the lack of using a very powerful python feature which caused this bug.

Comment: @zuberuber -- Fair enough, but it is useless as far as the code you posted is concerned. :-).  As far as I knew, you might have a misunderstanding about how the loops work and I thought that pointing out that `i` wasn't used after you increment it might help you out.  Also note that the same could be written as `i += 1`.

Comment: upvoted but it is not what i was looking for. @learner answer my question. thanks anyway for great tip